# Is using the HTML style tag bad practice? How else can I accomplish this?

Tags: php, html, refactoring

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
<?php
if ($x == 0)
  $image = 'background-position: 0px -7px';
else
  $image = 'background-position: 0px -14px';
?>
<a class="asdf" style="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a>
```

Is this the recommended way to change an image based on a variable in HTML/PHP? Is there any way to refactor this?

Comment: can you rewrite that so it's valid

Comment: Please, revise Your code, it's having some logic errors, with the x variable (also, use $ as a variable prefix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $positionClass = ($x == 0) ? 'position1' : 'position2';
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .position1 { background-position: 0px -7px; }
    .position2 { background-position: 0px -14px; }
</style>
<a class="asdf <?php echo $positionClass;?>"></a>
```

PHP will set which class should be used, and then echo the corresponding class in your HTML.  The CSS will be applied with the desired positioning attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of the style, use css and classes. If it's part of the content, you should be using an `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

You're code is weird? At the end of the if-statement the position would end up begin -7 or -14px... the first is just nonsense...

thus this code might be 'neat'-er but thats just personal:

```
<a class="asdf" style="background-position: 0px -<?php echo (($x==0)?'7':'14') ?>px;"></a>
```

Again, some might argue that this inline tenerary operator might be unreadable, but it does the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set a class instead, and change the class via PHP.  This way, you are still maintaining style in your CSS, but can choose it with PHP.